# What environment variables affect the 'java' binary?

Tags: java, environment-variables, invocation

Most unix commands whose operation changes based on values of environment variables have a section "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES" in their man page. No such luck for the java binary (Sun/Oracle Java 6), though I'm fairly certain that things like CLASSPATH and perhaps JVM_OPTS have an effect.

Can anyone point me to a list of environment variables that affect the 'java' binary?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are that many, but it will depend on what implementation (oracle vs ibm).

IBM's JDK has a list here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/appendixes/env_var/env_jvm.html

The oracle JDK has, at the very least, **CLASSPATH**, **JAVA_HOME** and **JRE_HOME**. Although in the man page for "java", the only environment variable it mentions is CLASSPATH.

Other tools like *ant* or *tomcat* may look for **JVM_OPTS**, and *JBoss* uses **JAVA_OPTS**.

Comment: yep, that link is exactly what i want, except I want it for Oracle.

Comment: I think the only one that the "java" binary cares about it **CLASSPATH** (based on the man page). Any listing from Oracle seems to want you to use command line options.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete answer to my own question:

Oracle [has a list for Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/bugreports003.html#CHDHHHBJ) of env variables to include when reporting a bug. Not really documentation, and no guarantee it's complete, but it is highly suggestive:

- `JAVA_HOME`
- `JRE_HOME`
- `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`
- `_JAVA_OPTIONS`
- `CLASSPATH`
- `JAVA_COMPILER`

There is specific documentation on [`JAVA_HOME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars001.html#CIHEEHEI) and [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html#CIHDGJHI)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `JAVA_HOME` to the installation directory and adding `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the PATH sould be enough, if you don't have to configure build systems like maven or ant.

`CLASSPATH` is required on most start scripts to contain the location of supporting libraries (.jar) or third-party stuff.

`JAVA_OPTS` usualy contains parameters for setting heap-space, debug agent and things like that.

AFAIK java itself does not depend on environment settings, rather start scripts, init services and anything build around.

Thus you won't find a single list of all environment variables related to java (software-products).

Comment: Is `JAVA_HOME` actually a specified JRE envvar? As opposed to a convention application / appserver authors seem to agree on unanimously as a way of choosing the location of the JRE to use?

Comment: @Inerdial I think it is rather a convention, than a technical requirement.

Comment: This is not helpful; I am specifically asking about the java binary. I am perfectly aware that wrapper scripts may look at whatever environment variables they want to.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html), which works for all JVM invocations, including applets and Webstart.